# Why is $P(X<0)$ the same as $P(X\le 0)$ for continuous distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

In uniform distribution, a continuous distribution, for example where $A = -1$ and $B = 1$, 
$P(X < 0)$ is said to be the same as $P(X \le 0)$. Why is this?

Comment: Because the set $\{X = 0\}$ is a set of measure zero. Or easier $\int_0^0 f(x) \, dx = 0$ for any $f$.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't really get it. What do you mean by "Measure" zero?

Comment: more generally, $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$ if $a=b$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, *continuous distribution* means $P(X=c)=0$ for every $c$.  Thus in your case $P(X=0)=0$, and this is the difference between the two probabilities you mention.

Note, though, that *continuous* does not imply *absolutely continuous*, so the distribution may not be of the form $P(X \in A) = \int_A f(x) dx$ for any function $f$.  The word *continuous* comes from writing the distribution as $P(X \in A) = \int_A \,dF(x)$ in Stieltjes form, and requiring $F$ to be continuous.

Comment: +1: I supposed the absolute continuity so your answer more related to the question

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean with $A,B$ but I suppose that with a continuous distribution you mean a distribution on the real line which has a density, i.e.
$$
P(X\in [a,b]) = \int\limits_a^bf(x)\,dx.
$$
Note that
$$
P(X\leq 0) = P(X<0)+P(X=0) = P(X<0)+\int\limits_{0}^0f(x)dx
$$
and the latter integral is zero as Jonas has written.